# Invalid salt error when comparing plain text and hash with bcrypt

Tags: python, hash, compare, bcrypt, salt

I'm trying to compare a saved hash and a user input in python using bcrypt. My code:

```
while passnotcorrect == True:
            password = input("Enter password: ")
            password = password.encode('utf-8')
            file = open('password.txt', 'r')
            checkhash = file.read()
            file.close()
            checkhash = checkhash.encode('utf-8')
            if bcrypt.checkpw(password, checkhash):
                passnotcorrect = False
                os.system('cls||clear')
            else:
                print("Password is incorrect \n")
```

The error:

> ValueError: Invalid salt

I'd really like some help with this. I'm not sure why this function would require the salt in the first place. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little late but I think your issue is that you're trying to compare 'password' which is utf8 encoded string input with 'checkhash', another string read from a file.

Bcrypt.checkpw() takes in a UTF8 encoded string for the password to check as the first argument followed by the UTF8 encoded **hash** to compare the password being provided against to see if the provided pass matches the hash pass.

TLDR; you're passing two strings to the checkpw method, when the second argument needs to be the hash you're comparing against (gold standard).

```
db_pass = "pw-string123"  # from database
password = "pw-string123"  # from input
db_hashed_pass = bcrypt.hashpw(db_pass.encode('utf8'), bcrypt.gensalt())
print(f'Hashed pass to save in db: {db_hashed_pass}')
is_pass_matching = bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode('utf8'), db_hashed_pass)

print(f'Do passwords match? {is_pass_matching}')
```

Make sure your hashed password isn't being truncated (length matches) upon entry or retrieval.

Comment: I just gave up and used hashlib lol. Thanks for the answer, looks like that was my issue. Thanks

Comment: My pleasure, sorry for being late to the party lol! Good luck on future projects :)